# How to Maintain Scientific Notation when Adding Asterisks

Tags: excel

I have a punch of P-values that I want to keep in scientific notation that I want to keep that way for tidiness' sake. However, I have to add asterisks to show level of significance. When I do, say, =E2 & F2 (E2 being the p-value and F2 being the asterisks in question), it shows the entire p-value rather than the shortened p-value under scientific notation (ie, it shows 0.00000000292929* instead of 2.93E-9*). Is there a way to maintain scientific notation while adding asterisks?

Comment: Maybe just use a custom number format for those cells? `0.00E+##\*` and the values would remain numeric.

Comment: Use the `TEXT` function:  `Something like `=TEXT(E2,"0.00E+#")&F2` for example, depending on exactly how you need to format the scientific notation part.